# Moved from dev to prod server, admin page blank

Tags: control-panel, admin

I have a dev server (sandbox.site.com) and a prod server (www.site.com). I copied over the contents from sandbox to dev using cp -r. Loading up my website on the production site looks fine. Everything is where it should be, the few entries I have in place loaded, images are there, etc.

The problem comes when trying to load the admin panel; I get a white screen. I enabled devMode and that gave me the login fields with no styling. I am unable to login (99% certain I have the user/pw right) and there are no error messages.

I searched for "error" in my craft.log, but nothing really stood out at me. I have a lot of the following errors:

```
[exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /home/user/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59
```

but the timestamp isn't the same time as trying to login to the control panel.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So with devMode enabled, the login page loads, but with no styling? Are the resources (CSS/JS) 404'ing if you look in your browser's console?

Comment: This is probably a permission error of the storage folder. I had this recently. The folder had the wrong ftp user. The reason you can see the frontend is because all files have been generated on your dev einvironement. If you delete the storage folder. The frontend won't show up anymore.

Comment: @BradBell - Ah, apparently yes. Lots of 404 errors. I'm confused as to why this would happen: I'm using the same craft folder for both my sandbox and my prod server. I changed the site url settings to point to my regular site as well. What'd I miss?

Comment: @KSPR I checked the storage folder and it's set to me as a user (with permissions set at 744). And as stated to Brad, it's the same folder as when I had a working copy on my sandbox. Which confuses me now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem - the htaccess file was still the old EE file that had been there. Once I uploaded the Craft-provided htaccess file, I was able to get back into the control panel. Thanks for the help guys!