# Settings in Admin Panel Blank

Tags: control-panel, admin, settings

Have kind of a weird problem going on with my site, which I just moved over from my staging server to production. Originally, everything looked fine, except I couldn't get into the Admin Panel. I discovered that I had an old .htaccess file in my root directory, and once I replaced that with the Craft CMS one, I was able to login just fine. Now, however, I've noticed that while most of the options on the left (Assets, Entries, Categories, etc) work as expected, if I select Settings, I'm greeted by a blank page. Any ideas?

My [previous question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14792/moved-from-dev-to-prod-server-admin-page-blank/14820#14820) as mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a chance that one of your plugins is causing this behavior. Go into your `craft_plugins` table, and change the value of `enabled` to `0` for every single plugin.

If your Settings page is then accessible, cautiously re-enable each plugin one-by-one. This will help you hone in on which plugin may be causing the problem.

Comment: Bingo. The Contact Form from Pixel & Tonic (which was the only Plugin I had installed) was the culprit. I'm fairly certain it wasn't the code in the plugin, so much as when I moved it over that caused issues.